# tensorflowをJDKで動かしたいが，エラーが出る

Tags: java, tensorflow

javaでtensorflowを使用しようとしているのですが，
チュートリアル：https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java中のTensorFlow with the JDKの通りに必要なものをダウンロードし，コンパイルまではできたのですが，

```
java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;. -Djava.library.path=.\jni HelloTensorFlow
```

とターミナルに入力して動かそうとすると

> エラー: メイン・クラス.library.path=.\jniが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした

とエラーを返されます．
パスの設定方法やファイル構成等，チュートリアルより詳細に教えていただけると幸いです．

現在の私の環境は，

- OS: windows10(64bit)
- java version: 1.8.0_191
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

各ファイルの構成は

```
├ jni/
│ ├ LICENSE
│ └ tensorflow_jni.dll
├ HelloTF.java
├ HelloTF.class
└ libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar
```

という具合です．
よろしくお願いします．

Comment: ``java.library.path=`` の指定で ``.\`` を付けずに実行するとどうなるでしょうか (チュートリアルには ``.\`` の指定がありません)。

Comment: > エラー: メイン・クラス.library.path=jniが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした と出てきます．同じです．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;. -Djava. library.path=.\jni HelloTensorFlow
```

実際に試してみたところ、上記のコマンド実行で再現しました。
**「-Djava.」の後にスペースが入っていないでしょうか？**

```
C:\work\20181107\>java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;. -Djava. library.path=.\jni HelloTensorFlow
エラー: メイン・クラスlibrary.path=.\jniを検出およびロードできませんでした
原因: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: library.path=.\jni
```

---

また、JavaはClass名とファイル名は一致している必要があるため、「HelloTF.class」である場合は、実際のファイルの中身も「HelloTF」となっているかと思われます。
っとなるとコマンド自体も↓でなければ正しく実行できないかと思われます。

```
java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;. -Djava.library.path=.\jni HelloTF
```

---

コメントの内容で解決したようなのでコメント欄から転記します。
PowerShellで実行する場合には、下記のようにクラスパスの値とシステムプロパティの設定をダブルクォーテーションで囲う必要があるようです。

```
java -cp "libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;." "-Djava.library.path=.\jni" HelloTensorFlow
```

何故、PowerShellの場合にダブルクォーテーションで囲う必要があるかについては、PowerShellの仕様については詳しくないため、参考のURLを記載するだけに致します。（公式ドキュメントはみつかりませんでした。）

- [Why does PowerShell split arguments containing hyphens and periods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704867)

  - 本家Stack Overflow
- [period in arguments](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/62d48584-fe25-43d5-8693-4c9b946cc1d4)

  - MicrosoftのQAサイト？
- [PowerShellコマンド環境で引っかかったこと](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/torutk/20160517/p1)

  - 日本語情報（↑↑のStack Overflowにたどり着いています）

Comment: java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar:. -Djava.library.path=.\jni HelloTF
エラー: メイン・クラス.library.path=.\jniが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした   と出てきます．

Comment: コマンド中のコロンをセミコロンにすると `. : 用語 '-Djava' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前が正しく記述されていることを確認し、
パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:37
+ java -cp libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;. -Djava.library.path=.\jni HelloTF
+                                     ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Djava:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`　と出てきました．-Djavaというオプションが一体何なのかさっぱりで…

Comment: -Dはシステムプロパティを設定するオプションです。今回は「java.library.path」という名前で「.\jni」を設定しています。詳細は→「 http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/application.html#java_option 」

Comment: で、「-cp」の値である「libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar:.」がコロンかセミコロンかの話ですが、これはWindowsであれば「;」が正しいはずです。（一応確認ですが、コマンドプロンプト上で実行しているという認識で良いですよね？）

Comment: PowerShellでやってました．cmdで同じコマンド打ったら動きました．ありがとうございます．   `I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2`  と警告は出てきましたが，無事  `Hello from 1.11.0`  と出力されました．

Comment: PowerShellの仕様は良くわかりませんが、オプションが正しく解釈されないようですね。ダブルクォーテーションで囲むことでPowerShellでも動作する事を確認しました。 ```java -cp "libtensorflow-1.11.0.jar;." "-Djava.library.path=.\jni" HelloTensorFlow```

Comment: 「PowerShellでは、ハイフン（「-」）で始まり途中にピリオド（「.」）を含む文字列があると、ピリオドの前で分割する振る舞いをするようです。」という記述を見つけましたので、参考にURLを貼っておきます。 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/torutk/20160517/p1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704867/why-does-powershell-split-arguments-containing-hyphens-and-periods